# Alter tablespace offline not working

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Why is the ALTER TABLESPACE OFFLINE command still leaving the table space 'USERS' in 'READ ONLY' mode?

Am I missing something/doing something wrong?

```
SQL> select user from dual;

USER
------------------------------
SYS

SQL> ALTER TABLESPACE USERS OFFLINE IMMEDIATE;

Tablespace altered.

SQL> SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME, STATUS, CONTENTS FROM DBA_TABLESPACES;

TABLESPACE_NAME                STATUS    CONTENTS
------------------------------ --------- ---------
SYSTEM                         ONLINE    PERMANENT
SYSAUX                         ONLINE    PERMANENT
UNDOTBS1                       ONLINE    UNDO
TEMP                           ONLINE    TEMPORARY
USERS                          READ ONLY PERMANENT
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it is read-only. You can check the datafile status in dba_data_files:

```
select file_id, file_name, tablespace_name, online_status;
```

There it should be reported as 'OFFLINE'.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on Oracle version.
After taking offline read-only tablespace, status column of dba_tablespaces view shows:

> 10g: offline
>
> 11g: read-only
>
> 12c: read-only

But on both versions you can check ONLINE_STATUS of tablespace by selecting DBA_DATA_FILES view:

```
select file_name,tablespace_name,online_status 
from  dba_data_files;
```